# 3rd party access to Magento CE downloadable products

Tags: android, ios, rest, magento, soap

Having migrated from a legacy system to Magento, I would like to allow access data on my magento store from an:

- iOS app
- Android app
- Web app

for the following:

- Product details inc image (straight-forward)
- **Downloadable product link** so we can sell our products as inapp purchases via our existing ios/android apps our users already use (currently connected to legacy system for this purpose) and also potentially make this same api available to other 3rd parties wishing to sell our products

Most important is the functioning of the apps. Fulfilment of the sale would not be via Magento but via in-app purchases. The apps just need to get product listings data and download links for successful sales.

Having looked at the documentation, it appears that REST (preferred) does not support this, but SOAP might http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/catalog/catalogProductDownloadableLink/product_downloadable_link.list.html.

I would like to provide an api where 2 or 3 calls can achieve the above to make integration into a 3rd party app easy and REST would be best.

Are there any extensions or alternative products out there which could fulfill this need or should I focus on working with the SOAP api (no expertise there) or should I look at ways to simply connect directly to the underlying mysql database to retrieve the relevant data.

Comment: Refer  http://magento.com/blog/magento-news/introducing-enterprise-edition-1142 (Magento Mobile Software Development Kit for iOS). It might help.

Comment: Ahh many thanks I will edit - my question - I have CE 1.9.2 currently - this appears to be Enterprise edition only - shame as it looks like it could be very useful